# show/hide css menu item depending user role using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the css layout: One column fixed width layout, from [maxdesign.com](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/)

I have two menu items defined like the following:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Data Entry</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Now, let's say that I have two roles: `guest` and `operator`, and I want that for example if a user with role `guest` is logged in, then just the `Report` item from the menu appear, and in case of a user `operator` is logged in, then both options appear.

How can I accomplish that?

**EDIT:**

Based on your responses, I'll go with the server side logic to deal with this:

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbDataEntry" runat="server">Data Entry</asp:LinkButton></li>
            <li><asp:LinkButton ID="lkbReports" runat="server">Reports</asp:LinkButton></li>                
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that is purely through CSS/initial load of the page? No postbacks or server-side controls allowed?

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with CSS. Yes you could add a class and hide the menu item – but wouldn't it  be better to only inset the needed items in the ASP script?

Comment: whatever solution is welcome :)

Comment: This should be handled server side, not client side.  Don't render content if the user shouldn't see it at all.  What happens when someone comes along without JS/CSS?  Do you want spiders going to your Data Entry page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this in the Page_Load..

```
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

    If Not cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Me.GetType(), "RoleVariable") Then
        Dim js As New String
        js = "var _role = " & role & ";"
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "RoleVariable", js, True)
    End If
```

And from there, you will have the role in the Javascript realm, where you can manipulate the visibility of the items you want.

So...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideStuff() {
        if (_role === "operator") {
            // hide/show your elements here
        }
        else if (_role === "guest") {
            // hide/show your elements here
        }
    }
</script>
```

Keep in mind that this approach is all client-side and is therefore easy for another developer to manipulate if they *really* wanted to. But on the other hand, it's the simplest. Don't use this approach for high-security situations.

Comment: (selected response) Since this approach does what I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You could give your menu elements an ID attribute and then in your codebehind either use [RegisterClientSideScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) or use [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to send JavaScript to the client to hide (or show) elements based on some condition.

Answer (score 1):

how about something simple like?

```
<% if(Page.User.IsInRole("operator") || Page.User.IsInRole("guest")) { %>
<div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <% if(Page.User.IsInRole("operator")) { %>
            <li><a href="#">Data Entry</a></li>
            <% } %>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: of course this is assuming you are using .NET and Membership, and really, you should be using server side code for logic operations like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% think you can (or should) be doing logic operations with stylesheets. You may need to have some javascript and then decide based on guest or operator which style to display